# How best to search specific tags with PHP and JS in MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, ajax

How best to search for an item that only has tags users search for, whether it has all of the tags or just some of the tags?

So for instance:

```
item   |   param
-----------------
1      |   a
1      |   b
1      |   c

2      |   b
2      |   c
2      |   d

3      |   c
3      |   d
3      |   e

4      |   d
4      |   e
4      |   f
```

item 1 has a,b,c; item 2 has b,c,d; item 3 has c,d,e; item 4 has d,e,f

User input into search bar with params a,c,d,e,g; 1 and 2 have b and 4 has f which are outside user's params. So only item 3 because it has only c,d,e and nothing else and these 3 params fall into user's params. It does not have a or g, but that does not matter.

I can only think of a few ways to do this. And the best way I can think of is:

1: In another table, say the main table for the items, store the number of tags this item has.

2: Loop query through the entire table using parameters like `WHERE (param=$user_para[$key])` one param at a time. Every time a param gets matched, the item id gets added to an array.

3: After the loop finishes, an algorithm counts how many times an item id appears in the array and compares to the number of tags in the main table. If it's less than the stored number (so something other than the tags user wants is in  that item), then array removes all of that item id and checks the next one.

I feel like this is still very bad. What is a better solution to this?

I put JS/AJAX in the tag because I want to know what can be done in front end instead of putting more stress on the back end.

Comment: Please clarify. If the user searches for `c,d,e,f,g,h`  would an item that has `c,d,k` be a match?

Comment: No, since k is not in the user's search parameter

Comment: Ok I got it. My approach is a bit different from yours but should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** split the parameters you get from the user into an array and build the `WHERE` part of the SQL query. Suppose user wants params `a,b`:

```
$input = $_POST['params']; // eg: a,b
$params = explode(',', $input); // eg: [a,b]
$qry_params =[]; //holds the processed parameters 

//todo: here you want to escape each input param to prevent SQL injection

foreach($params as $param) $qry_params[] = "params like '%$param%'";    

//$where will be: where params like '%a%' or params like '%b%'
$where = " where ".implode(" or ",$qry_params);
```

**2.** Use an SQL query that will give you all params grouped by item. Note that `$where` is at the bottom

```
select * from(
    select item, GROUP_CONCAT(param) as params
    from tbl
    group by item
) t
where params like '%a%' or params like '%b%'
```

[**See the result set**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b963/10)

```
item | params
-------------
1    | a,b,c,d
2    | e,d,c,b
```

**3.** Now you have all items that have at least one of the params the user requested. The last step is to loop through results and get rid of those with parameters the user never asked for

Suppose all the db records returned are put in a `$rows` array

```
$matches = []; // final result
foreach($rows as $row){
    $dbParams = explode(',', $row['params']); eg: [a,b,c,d] for item 1

    //array_diff returns array of values in $dbParams not found in $params
    //if there is no such value (db has no extras the user doesn't want)
    //add the current row to matches.   
    if(!array_diff($dbParams,$params)) $matches[] = $row;
}
```

At this point `$matches` is the subset of the result set from earlier that satisfies your requirements.

Comment: Seems somewhat simpler than mine. I'll give it a try when i get home. I need to play around with the query commands more, I didn't know there are features like group_concat.

Comment: @J13t0u It's a lot simpler than what you suggested: it doesn't rely on a 2nd table, and more importantly it doesn't rely on executing multiple queries in a loop (which makes this a lot faster as well).  SQL is really powerful; I wouldn't be surprised if there were a way to get the exact result you seek with just the right query. I just don't have that skill level yet.

Comment: I asked another question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38576706/how-to-find-out-how-many-times-a-mysql-comparison-query-returns-true-and-false/
Going get your method work first, then try his query.

Comment: @J13t0u If you chose to try implementing my solution, then please select it. It may not look like it in my post, but it takes a long time to work out a lean solution to a problem such as this, to test it and then to write up instructions for your benefit.  About your other question: i think you received a pretty clever answer; I wouldn't know how to do that without doing some research myself.

Comment: Oh yes, forgot about selecting it. Trying to convert it into PDO and it's kind of a pain.