# How to find out how many times a MySQL comparison query returns true and false?

Tags: mysql

I'm not sure how to make the title more clear, but here's what I mean:

```
SELECT item FROM tbl WHERE tag like '%a%' OR tag like '%b%' OR tag like '%c%'
```

The like comparison functions return true and false. Here's my question, is there a feature that tracks how many times it returns true and false. Especially in the case where you GROUP the items and group_concat the tags.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are asking.
This will return as count how many where clause out of the three clauses are satisfied.

```
SELECT item, (IF(tag like '%a%',1,0)+IF(tag like '%b%',1,0)+IF(tag like '%c%',1,0)) as count
FROM tb
WHERE tag like '%a%' OR tag like '%b%' OR tag like '%c%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how many result is true and how many result is false, you could use the `UNION` statement:

```
SELECT 'true', COUNT(item) FROM tbl WHERE tag LIKE '%a%' OR tag LIKE '%b%' OR tag LIKE '%c%'
UNION
SELECT 'false', COUNT(item) FROM tbl WHERE tag NOT LIKE '%a%' AND tag NOT LIKE '%b%' AND tag NOT LIKE '%c%');
```

I've put them on 3 lines for readability but you can write it on one line like this: `SELECT 'true', COUNT(item) FROM tbl WHERE tag LIKE '%a%' OR tag LIKE '%b%' OR tag LIKE '%c%' UNION SELECT 'false', COUNT(item) FROM tbl WHERE tag NOT LIKE '%a%' AND tag NOT LIKE '%b%' AND tag NOT LIKE '%c%');`

The result of this query will be:

```
+-------------+
+ true  + 250 +
+-------+-----+
+ false + 10  +
+-------------+
```